# How did the players between the group to group rounds get allocated in the Homestory Cup IV?

Tags: starcraft-2

I was watching the [Homestory Cup IV](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/HomeStory_Cup/4) yesterday, and I caught some of the "reseeding" between the Ro32 (8 groups of 4) and Ro16 (4 of 4) group stages and didn't really know what was going on.  Players seemed to be suggesting different group matchups, but I don't know if they were just throwing out ideas then having people agree on it, or if was somehow ordered.  They were saying "(Player X) can switch (player Y) into group Z", which makes me think the latter, but I don't know of any common rules for such an event.

Liquipedia just says "The Top 4 players, based on map score, from Group Stage #1 will be able to switch their groups in Group Stage #2", do they just give #1 first choice and on down?

Answer (score 1):

From what I heard of the seeding, players got to choose which group they got into. But nothing beyond that.

So from the round of 32 the top two would get to choose which empty group of 4 they would go into. This allowed players to choose who they would go up against in their group. I didn't hear anything that allowed players to switch other players into other groups.

The fact that I do know is what I said earlier. Players got to choose which of the 4 remaining groups they were going to play in, unlike the GSL where the group select stage has them picking their opponents and it cascaded down that way.